# XMLHttpRequest object callback doesn't fire in crossdomain jquery/Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I've got this code:

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

       xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
           if (evt.lengthComputable) {
               var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
               console.log(percentComplete);
           }
       }, false);

       return xhr;
    },
  dataType: "jsonp",
  contentType: "text/javascript charset-utf-8",
  url: "http://*******.com/pcm/datamobile.asmx/ObtenerContactos",
  crossDomain: true, 
  timeout:8000000,
  data: {sessionId: 1},
  error : function (xhr, status) {

      },
 success : function() {FirstAjaxReady();} 
});   
}
```

The function in the xhr: option never fires. I'm trying to get a progress report on the request. This may have something to do with the fact that it is cross-domain. If so, is there a way to have a progress report in a cross-domain Ajax request?

Answer (score 1):

Crossdomain, or Cross-Origin, needs to be enabled on the server-side as well

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

And the CORS security does seem to dictate that progress will not be sent:

> CORS API specifications also need to ensure not to reveal anything
>   until the cross-origin request status is set to preflight complete or
>   success to prevent e.g. port scanning.
>
> In XMLHttpRequest progress events are dispatched only after the
>   cross-origin request status is set to success. Upload progress events
>   are only dispatched once the cross-origin request status is preflight
>   complete.

If I am reading that correctly.

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request

Comment: The ajax call itself works though. The only thing that doesn't is the xhr call. I'm also using jsonp as the datatype, which doesn't need the header.

Comment: The request succeeds and you get the success function?  It wasn't clear in your question, it sounded more like the request wasn't working.  So it succeeds but not using your XHR object?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The XHR object is not integral to the success of the call in this case, its just monitoring its progress.

Comment: That does seem consistent with the spec.  It appears your XHR object works as expected, just that the progress event is never sent util after success.  Is that what you are seeing?